# Test object in jest with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, arrow-functions

When I use `jest` with common functions, I have access to test object in `this`.

```
afterEach(function() {
  return this.hello; // 'Hello world!'
})

it(function() {
  this.hello = 'Hello world!';
})
```

When I use arrow functuions `this` means global context.

How I can access to test object, when I use arrow functions?

Comment: You can't because arrow function don't bind `this`.

Comment: The solution is simply to not use arrow functions when you need a method.